# dialogflow-fulfillment - Error: Request can NOT be empty

Tags: node.js, express, dialogflow-es

I am getting this error, but the request is not empty...

```
const {
  Pedido,
  buscaPedidos
} = require('../models/PedidosModel');

const {
  WebhookClient,
  Payload
} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

const { Carousel } = require('actions-on-google');

exports.bot = async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log(req.body);
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ req: req.body, res: res });
let conv = agent.conv();
conv.ask(new Carousel({
  items: {
    // Add the first item to the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_ONE]: {
      synonyms: [
        'synonym of title 1',
        'synonym of title 2',
        'synonym of title 3',
      ],
      title: 'Title of First Carousel Item',
      description: 'This is a description of a carousel item.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_AOG,
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
      }),
    },
    // Add the second item to the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_HOME]: {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Home Assistant',
        'Assistant on the Google Home',
    ],
      title: 'Google Home',
      description: 'Google Home is a voice-activated speaker powered by ' +
        'the Google Assistant.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME,
        alt: 'Google Home',
      }),
    },
    // Add third item to the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_PIXEL]: {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Pixel XL',
        'Pixel',
        'Pixel XL',
      ],
      title: 'Google Pixel',
      description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL,
        alt: 'Google Pixel',
      }),
    },
    // Add last item of the carousel
    [SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_ALLO]: {
      title: 'Google Allo',
      synonyms: [
        'Allo',
      ],
      description: 'Introducing Google Allo, a smart messaging app that ' +
        'helps you say more and do more.',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_GOOGLE_ALLO,
        alt: 'Google Allo Logo',
      }),
    },
  },
}));

agent.add(conv);
agent.send(conv);
}
```

The console.log of the req is showing

```
{
  responseId: '373f7c26-2802-41fa-8fe6-209bd7037aae-470ed8da',
  queryResult: {
    queryText: 'quero ver o menu',
    action: 'solicitando_cardapio',
    parameters: {},
    allRequiredParamsPresent: true,
    fulfillmentText: 'Desculpe, mas não estamos conseguindo acessar o sistema neste momento...',
    fulfillmentMessages: [ [Object] ],
    outputContexts: [ [Object] ],
    intent: {
      name: 'projects/hamburgueria-hw9g/agent/intents/edda994b-0943-4b28-9b17-961f406d5eca',
      displayName: 'solicitar_cardapio'
    },
    intentDetectionConfidence: 1,
    languageCode: 'pt-br'
  },
  originalDetectIntentRequest: { payload: {} },
  session: 'projects/hamburgueria-hw9g/agent/sessions/dfMessenger-73173927'
}
```

So, the request is not empty...
Could you please help me?

I tryed i lot of things, including ask to GPT, but GPT is not finding any problem with this final code.
I read others stackoverflows's questions, but any of then solved this, most of then ask to do what i am already doing:   const agent = new WebhookClient({ req: req.body, res: res });

So, I really can't solve it....

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate the `WebhookClient` in this way:

```
const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });
```

If you check the `dialogflow-fulfillment` github source code, the constructor validates the "request" property.

[WebhookClient Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8NvR.png)